# Php how to recieve and parse Content-Type: multipart/related;

Tags: php, php-7

I want to implement in php something like controller, that recieves something like https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#multipart

```
POST /files HTTP/1.1
Host: my-foo-host
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=test
Content-Length: 226

--test
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json; charset=UTF-8

{"data":{"some-meta-data-key":"some-meta-data-value"}}

--test
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-transfer-encoding: base64

UGNsYXNzIEZhcmUK
--test--
```

Are there any solutions for this in php to vaidate it and represent in something like:

```
php > $requestData = get_data();
php > foreach ($requestData as $dataItem) {
php >     echo $dataItem->getContentType() . PHP_EOL;
php >     echo $dataItem->getBody() . PHP_EOL;
php >     echo PHP_EOL;
php > }
application/vnd.api+json; charset=UTF-8
{"data":{"some-meta-data-key":"some-meta-data-value"}}

text/plain; charset=utf-8
UGNsYXNzIEZhcmUK
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look for solutions implementing the [PSR-7 recommendations](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/).
Or implement it by yourself.
[Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) would be an example of it.